# Retrieve data with ajax request from jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to retrieve data with jquery ajax request in laravel. I always get 500 internal server error on request. I want to auto load other fields in table when selecting the GRN no from selection. Any help to get rid of this error. My codes are below.

view - analysis.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-6 analysis-table">
        <div class="description-table-1">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <u><h5>Supply - 01</h5></u>
            <table id="grn_for_MC">
                <tr>
                    <td width="40%">GRN</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="grn-one" id="grn-one" class="input-sm dynamic" data-dependant="new-supply-data">
                            <option value="">Select GRN</option>
                            @foreach($grn_list as $grn_lists)
                            <option value="{{$grn_lists->id}}">{{$grn_lists->grn_no}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Supply Date</td>
                    <td id="load-supply-date">14/02/2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Supplier Name</td>
                    <td id="load-supplier">Mahesh Lowe</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quantity Supplied</td>
                    <td id="load-qty">10000.00kg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No of Bags</td>
                    <td id="load-no-of-bags">20</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My scripts are below.....

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('select#grn-one').on('change',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var selected_grn_id = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

        console.log(selected_grn_id);
        $.ajax({
            url:"/getGrnData/" + selected_grn_id,
            method: 'get',
            // data: {id:selected_grn_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(){
                console.log('Request Send');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

TestController.php

```
public function ajax_show($id)
{
    if(Request::ajax()){
        $grnId = Input::get("id");
        return Response::json('Success',$grnId);
    }
}
```

VeryfyCsrfToken.php

```
protected function tokensMatch($request){
    $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');
    return $request->session()->token() == $token;
}
```

Route....

```
Route::get('/getGrnData/{id}','TestController@ajax_show');
```

Comment: what was your exact error ?

Comment: You should probably include the routes as well.

Comment: @Qonvex620: my error is code 500 internal server error.

Comment: I am taking this error after I add this code fraction                                 return Response::json($request->all());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to question. View is not changed. TestController.php & Scripts are changed. I've just removed ajax validation within TestController function and just return the json response from function. Then it is captured from ajax and data will send to the requested scripts.

TestController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $loadData = DB::table('summery')->where('id',$id)->get();
    return response()->json($loadData);
}
```

Scripts....

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('select#grn-one').on('change',function(e){
        var selected_grn_id = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            url:'/getGrnData/'+selected_grn_id,
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    });

});
```